# Terminate incoming call by TelephonyManager on Android P is not working

Tags: xamarin.forms, android-9.0-pie

On Android 8 and below, i'm using TelephonyManager to terminate incoming call. But on android 9, my code is not working.
I found on Google docs, they said that we had an official API for rejecting calls on Android.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/TelecomManager#endCall()
But it's Java code. I don't know how to use that method in my xamarin project. 
By the way, do we have any way to terminate a phone call programmatically on Android 9?
Please help me. I am new to xamarin.

Comment: `endCall` could be used in Android P (since Beta 2) and above, based on my research, it cannot be used in Android 9 now.

Comment: :( So do we have any way to terminate a phone call in Android P?

Comment: Did you request the permission `Manifest.permission.ANSWER_PHONE_CALLS`?If 
 you did that, I found  only solution that could replace it, is by extending InCallService class, but by doing so you must also have your app become the default dialer app.